# Scroll Magic add indicators plugin not working

Tags: jquery, scrollmagic

I have started using the ScrollMagic library recently. When I tried using the addIndicators plugin in my program, it did not work properly. The trigger indicator is given by a very small blue tick (same with start and end indicators). My code is as follows.

HTML :

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <section id="landing">                                                              
        </section>
        <section id="home">             
        </section>
    </div>  
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.19.0/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/ScrollMagic.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/plugins/animation.gsap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/plugins/debug.addIndicators.min.js"></script> 
</body>
```

CSS :

```
            body, html {
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            body {
                width: 300%;
                overflow-y: hidden;
                overflow-x: scroll;
                margin: auto;   
                white-space: nowrap;
                font-size: 0;
            }
            #container {
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
                display:block;  
            }
            section {
                position: relative;
                display: inline-block;
                text-align: center;
                height: 100vh;
                width: 150vw;
            }
            #landing {
                background-color: yellow;
            }
            #home {
                background-color: orange;
            }
```

JQuery :

```
var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller({vertical: false});
var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({triggerElement: "#landing", duration: "150%", triggerHook: 0})
            .setPin("#landing")
            .addIndicators()                
            .addTo(controller);
```

I tried the code without the container too, but it did not work. What do I need to add, or what wrong order of code have I written?

https://jsfiddle.net/zjapLcx4/1/

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, the indicators are in place.

Comment: Really? They are not visible in my browser

Comment: Exactly, they are visible as small ticks. By default, the trigger indicator is supposed to have the name 'trigger', right? If not, how do I add it. The option .addIndicators({name: 'trigger'}) is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had `font-size: 0;`, (I took the liberty to clean up your code a bit).
I also changed the trigger to `#home` instead just for clarity of the trigger, start and end indicators.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zjapLcx4/4/)

html

```
<div id="container">
  <section id="landing"></section>
  <section id="home"></section>
</div>
```

css

```
body {
  width: 300%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

js

```
var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller({
  vertical: false
});

var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
    triggerElement: "#home",
    duration: "150%"
  })
  .setPin("#home")
  .addIndicators()
  .addTo(controller);
```

Comment: Wow! I didn't know that the font-size applied to that as well. I added it because of the messy white space which comes up between the divs. Can I find a way around that and still display the indicator name?

Comment: @Quasar well it's a known issue dealing with `inline-block`, can you use `flex` or `block`?

Comment: flex and block are ruining my website completely (this is just a snippet of the actual one). Inline-flex has the same issue. Btw, how is inline-flex different from inline-block?

Comment: @Quasar don't take this the wrong way, how are they ruining your site, what happens?

Comment: but can I put in the font-size: 0 and explicitly specify a font-size for the indicator? If yes, what is the attribut to be used?

Comment: It is a one-page horizontal scrolling website. All my different sections are getting stacked up in one place. I will have to position each of them separately, rather than letting them be stacked neatly in line

Comment: @Quasar I don't think you can do that, there is no target for the indicator font-size

Comment: @Quasar you can make it `flex`, you just have to set the `min-width`, https://jsfiddle.net/zjapLcx4/5/

Comment: Cool! I changed the container display to flex (originally block), and it worked! although I don't know exactly why. Thanks a bunch @Dejan!

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem like this, and it was solved when I placed ScrollMagic CDN on any of the GSAP CDN and it worked like a charm, So my suggestion for people with same problem like above is try moving the placement of CDN. I hope it works for you and others:)